# How to pass multidimensional array to a custom function in Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I want to pass a multidimensional array to a custom function. I do it like this:

```
=customFunction({{"a1v1"; "a1v2"};{"a2v1"; "a2v2"; "a2v3"};{"a3v1"}})
```

However, I don't get the expected behavior because it behaves like a 1-dimension array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not adding an *array* or *string* but an *object*. Objects are not processed as such and simply returned. Coincidentally, you discovered that a semi-colon creates a column presentation and a backslash a row presentation.

If you really want to add an array notation as a parameter, then you need to do the following.

### Formula

```
=customFunction("[['a1v1', 'a1v2'],['a2v1', 'a2v2', 'a2v3'],['a3v1']]")
```

### Code

```
function customFunction(multiArray) {
  return  eval(multiArray);  
}
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Explained

Prepare the string with single and double quotes, in order to use text within the array. This string is then evaluated, via the `eval()` method, as it if were JavaScript.