# Get all unique combinations of values from two tables where a 3rd value is equivalent google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I've got 2 tables and on a third table I want to have all unique combinations of table2.a, table1.b where table1.c==table2.c

`SELECT table2.a, table1.b FROM table1 JOIN table2 WHERE table1.c=table2.c`

In sql I would be using inner join or join (I think) but I can't seem to find a way to do this using google sheets query()

It doesn't need to join the actual keys together like I have in table3.a I have already added an arrayformula to handle that. The prefered output would be a 2d array that I can fill in table3.b:c

table1

```
a b c
  4 7
  5 8
  6 9
```

table2

```
a b c
1   7
2   8
3   9
```

table3 (wanted output)

```
a  b  c
14 1  4 
25 2  5
36 3  6
```

I've tried to replicate what I would use in sql to get the results I want, but to no avail as the query() method doesn't work the same.

Things I have tried.
`=query("SELECT" table1!A, table2!A "FROM "table1, table2" WHERE" table1!C = table2!C)` doesnt work and isn't the correct syntax

`=query({table1!A2:A; table2!A2:A})`
this gets me the list of both in one column,

`=query({table1!A2:C; table2!A2:C}, "select Col1 where Col2='3'")`
this gets me a list of all but only checks a single column (first column from both sheets) I think this is getting closer if i can find a way to set it to check a certain column from each sheet rather than the default Col1, Col2 etc.

Comment: Instead of `{table1!A2:C; table2!A2:C}` you could put `{table1!B2:C; table2!A2:A, table2!C2:C}` to align the columns. I don't see how this helps with forming all combinations, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) for this, to be used as

```
=combinations(table1!B2:B, table1!C2:C, table2!A2:A, table2!C2:C)
```

that is, the parameters are ValueColumn1, KeyColumn1, ValueColumn2, KeyColumn2.

The logic is entirely straightforward: run a double loop and collect whatever matches.

```
function combinations(range1, key1, range2, key2) {
  var output = [];
  if (range1.length != key1.length || range2.length != key2.length) {
    throw new Error('Each range must have the same length as its key'); 
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < range1.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < range2.length; j++) {
      if (key1[i][0] === key2[j][0] && key1[i][0] !== '') {
        output.push([range1[i][0], range2[j][0]]);
      }
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

Comment: yea I figured I would end up needing to write a function for it, I was hoping that there would be a way to do it with the built in functions.
thanks though :D

Comment: If there is, it's more complicated than writing a custom function. [Here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/86713) you can see the code for generating all combinations of values in two columns, but that's without checking that the keys match.