# Find duplicates across multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets

My spreadsheet contains information about companies and is structured ledger-like in this way:

```
Company   Quarter   Revenues   EBITDA
A         2010.1    5          1
A         2010.2    6          1
B         2010.1    10         2
B         2010.2    12         3
B         2010.3    20         5
A         2010.3    8          2
B         2011.1    14         3
A         2010.3    8          2
A         2010.4    7          2
A         2011.1    9          1
```

I want:

- a formula (not GAS) that will show me a list of duplicates for the combination Company-Quarter. In the above example, there are two entries for Company A for Quarter 2010.3. In the data there could be multiple duplicates.
- a formula (not GAS) that give me missing Company-quarters for a given quarters range for all companies that have at least one entry in the date range (or alternatively, from a pre-determined list of Companies). In the above example, for the range 2010.1 to 2011.1, there is no entry for Company B in 2010.4. In the data there could be multiple missing information.

Ideally, I won't need to create auxiliary columns and is all contained in one formula, so as to make the spreadsheet more elegant.

--- xxx ---

Thanks to @Tedinoz answer below, I came down to a one-cell formula, copied here for future reference:
`=unique(sort(arrayformula(if(arrayformula(isna(vlookup(unique(arrayformula(transpose(split(join("", arrayformula(rept(filter(UNIQUE(A2:A), len(UNIQUE(A2:A)))&char(9999), counta(transpose(split(join("", arrayformula(rept(filter(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),1,4))), len(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),1,4)))))&char(9999), counta(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),6,1))))))), char(9999)))  )))), char(9999)))  &" "&transpose(split(rept(join(char(9999), filter(arrayformula((transpose(split(join("", arrayformula(rept(filter(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),1,4))), len(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),1,4)))))&char(9999), counta(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),6,1))))))), char(9999)))  )&"."&(transpose(split(rept(join(char(9999), filter(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),6,1))), len(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),6,1))))))&char(9999), counta(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),1,4))))), char(9999))))), len(arrayformula((transpose(split(join("", arrayformula(rept(filter(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),1,4))), len(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),1,4)))))&char(9999), counta(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),6,1))))))), char(9999)))  )&"."&(transpose(split(rept(join(char(9999), filter(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),6,1))), len(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),6,1))))))&char(9999), counta(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),1,4))))), char(9999))))))))&char(9999), counta(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),1,4))))), char(9999))))),arrayformula(A2:A&" "&B2:B),1,0))),unique(arrayformula(transpose(split(join("", arrayformula(rept(filter(UNIQUE(A2:A), len(UNIQUE(A2:A)))&char(9999), counta(transpose(split(join("", arrayformula(rept(filter(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),1,4))), len(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),1,4)))))&char(9999), counta(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),6,1))))))), char(9999)))  )))), char(9999)))  &" "&transpose(split(rept(join(char(9999), filter(arrayformula((transpose(split(join("", arrayformula(rept(filter(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),1,4))), len(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),1,4)))))&char(9999), counta(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),6,1))))))), char(9999)))  )&"."&(transpose(split(rept(join(char(9999), filter(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),6,1))), len(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),6,1))))))&char(9999), counta(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),1,4))))), char(9999))))), len(arrayformula((transpose(split(join("", arrayformula(rept(filter(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),1,4))), len(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),1,4)))))&char(9999), counta(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),6,1))))))), char(9999)))  )&"."&(transpose(split(rept(join(char(9999), filter(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),6,1))), len(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),6,1))))))&char(9999), counta(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),1,4))))), char(9999))))))))&char(9999), counta(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B),1,4))))), char(9999))))),""))))`

Comment: https://spreadsheetpoint.com/highlight-duplicates-google-sheets/

Comment: Thanks @User24601! Part one is solved using conditional formatting and the following formula: =COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA($A2:$A&$B2:$B),$A2&$B2)>1

Comment: @OrenPinsky This formula doesn't work for me. A 2010.3 isn't highlighted as a duplicate.

Comment: @Tedinoz, it works for me. It highlights one of the duplicates, in a similar fashion to your answer to part 1 below. Many, many thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DUPLICATE COMPANY-QUARTERS**

- Insert this formula in Cell E2:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIFS(A2:A11&B2:B11&C2:C11,A2:A11&B2:B11&C2:C11,ROW(A2:A11),"<="&ROW(A2:A11)))`

- There is only one duplicate in the OP data: "A 2010.3"

---

[image: Snapshot]

---

**MISSING COMPANY-QUARTERS**

You want a formula that gives missing Company-quarters for a given quarters range for all companies that have at least one entry in the date range.

- **Existing Company/Quarter**

  - Cell E2, enter this formula:

  `=arrayformula(A2:A11&" "&B2:B11)`

  - This is a helper cell/column. It builds a column of values of the existing Company/Quarter.
- **All combinations of Company/Year/Quarter**

  - Cell F2, enter this formula:

`=arrayformula(transpose(split(join("", arrayformula(rept(filter(UNIQUE(A2:A11), len(UNIQUE(A2:A11)))&char(9999), counta(transpose(split(join("", arrayformula(rept(filter(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B11),1,4))), len(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B11),1,4)))))&char(9999), counta(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B11),6,1))))))), char(9999)))  )))), char(9999)))  &" "&transpose(split(rept(join(char(9999), filter(arrayformula((transpose(split(join("", arrayformula(rept(filter(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B11),1,4))), len(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B11),1,4)))))&char(9999), counta(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B11),6,1))))))), char(9999)))  )&"."&(transpose(split(rept(join(char(9999), filter(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B11),6,1))), len(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B11),6,1))))))&char(9999), counta(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B11),1,4))))), char(9999))))), len(arrayformula((transpose(split(join("", arrayformula(rept(filter(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B11),1,4))), len(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B11),1,4)))))&char(9999), counta(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B11),6,1))))))), char(9999)))  )&"."&(transpose(split(rept(join(char(9999), filter(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B11),6,1))), len(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B11),6,1))))))&char(9999), counta(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B11),1,4))))), char(9999))))))))&char(9999), counta(arrayformula(unique(mid(query(B2:B11),1,4))))), char(9999))))`

- This creates a list of every combination of the Company, Year and Quarter.
- **Detecting mismatches**

  - Cell G2, enter this formula:

`=arrayformula(isna(vlookup(F2:F17,$E$2:$E$11,1,0)))`

- Values that return FALSE represent combinations that exist in the data list.
- Values that return TRUE represent a Coy/Year/Quarter that is missing from the data list.

---

[image: Snapshot]

---

**Credit:**

[Combine two columns into a list of all possible combinations of entries](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/86713/196152) (webapps.stackexchange)

Comment: Fantastic, thank you Tedinoz!

I've put all of the columns in one formula, to remove the need for auxiliary columns, and also made the formulas resiliant to an increase in the number of rows. The formula is probably the longest i've ever seen in Sheets and don't fit in the comments