# Duplicating rows in a Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

Suppose I have a Google Sheet of companies:

```
Company Name, Link
Apple, Apple.com
Google, Google.com
PayPal, PayPal.com
```

and roles:

```
Role
CEO
CTO
CFO
```

How would I create a Google Sheet that "matrix multiples" them so I get:

```
Company Name, Role, Link
Apple         CEO   Apple.com
Apple         CTO   Apple.com
Apple         CFO   Apple.com
Google        CEO   Google.com
Google        CTO   Google.com
Google        CFO   Google.com
PayPal        CEO   PayPal.com
PayPal        CTO   PayPal.com
PayPal        CFO   PayPal.com
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine two columns into a list of all possible combinations of entries](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/86711/combine-two-columns-into-a-list-of-all-possible-combinations-of-entries)

Comment: @Rubén I tried looking at https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/84405/show-all-combinations-for-a-selection-of-columns and this gets me close. However It's not quite like the above since it doesn't split this into multiple columns

Comment: Please edit your question and include what you tried and why the referred Q&A doesn't help you.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "matrix multiples"? Have you tried [`rept`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094134)?